# A list of all the applescript data types

Tags: applescript

Could someone please give a list of all the applescript data types (the things in bold below):

`set x to "x" as`**`text`**

`set x to 123 as`**`integer`**

---

---

**Update:** The following webpage is best:

> http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24695

---

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: It seems to be a data type but Apple's docs don't mention this in the `set` command.

Comment: Those would be 'types' in normal programming language parlance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one list of types that may or may not be exhaustive:

http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/smile/computing/as_types/as_data_types.html

Comment: Thanks. I have also found this one: http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24695